# Google map and Google Analytics on the same page, google map css, fonts are taking first place in the header

Tags: google-maps, google-analytics

Google Map and Google Analytics on the same page, here I need to display the analytics code as the first one but automatically google map Css taking the first place in the header. how could load the analytics as first one in the header section?
also, google captcha taking the second place, please help me to sort out this problem 
FYR I have attached the screenshot : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/quhRG.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bother too much about that. Google Analytics is loaded on the pages asynchronously, meaning that you can't determine the location in the HTML code served to the visitor.
Also, GA loading a couple of lines below the opening  is more than good enough and doesn't pose a threat or a big difference in the performance of the tracking because of it.